# Facetime mutes all other sounds after Mavericks OS update

Tags: audio, macos, facetime, sound-volume

I like to FaceTime and watch movies, Youtube clips etc. at the same time and I have been able to do this perfectly up until the Mavericks OS update.

Ever since the update for some reason when I'm using FaceTime all other sounds are decreased to a great extend. Using Skype is not an option since it does not have noise reduction. Would anyone know a fix or workaround for this problem, it's getting a real pain in the ass, or would downgrading be my only option? Or could it maybe be possible to install a previous version of just FaceTime?

All ideas are welcome!